# How to fill enumerated element with images from checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, checkbox

I am trying to create a compare function, where users can click a checkbox and it sends an associated image to an enumerated list.

Here is my list code:

```
<div class="compareTray">
    <ul>
        <li class="item_0"></li>
        <li class="item_1"></li>
        <li class="item_2"></li>
        <li class="item_3"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is sample HTML that the user will click from to populate the above list:

```
<div class="project1 clearfix">
          <figure> <img src="images/submenu/submenu-1.png" alt="img"/>
            <div class="overlay"> <a href="#">DETAILS</a> </div>
          </figure>
          <div class="project-detail">
            <h3>PRODUCT</h3>
            <span class="span-red"> </span>
            <p class="lot"><strong>Location</strong>: LOT NAME</p>
            <p class="rating"><strong>Customer Rating</strong>: Not enough ratings yet</p>
            <div class="compare-btn clearfix">
              <input type="checkbox" id="stockno1"/>
              Compare </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="project1 clearfix">
          <figure> <img src="images/submenu/submenu-2.png" alt="img"/>
            <div class="overlay"> <a href="#">DETAILS</a> </div>
          </figure>
          <div class="project-detail">
            <h3>PRODUCT</h3>
            <span class="span-red"> </span> 
            <p class="lot"><strong>Location</strong>: LOT NAME</p>
            <p class="rating"><strong>Customer Rating</strong>: Not enough ratings yet</p>
            <div class="compare-btn clearfix">
              <input type="checkbox" id="stockno2"/>
              Compare </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And here is my script:

```
$('input.compare').click(function(){
    var i = 0;
    alert("i before: " + i);
    for( var i = 0; i < 5;  ) {
        var me = $(this).attr("refid"); 
        var item =  "li[class^=item_"+ i + "]"
        alert(item);
        $('.item_'+ i).append('<img src="images/submenu/' + me + '.png" alt="compare1" height="28" width="28" />');
        //++i;
        i = i +1;
        alert("i after: " + i);
    }
});
```

Right now, if any one of the compare-btn checkboxes is clicked, it iterates through the entire loop and fills the entire list with the same item. What I want to do is populate the first list item with the first item clicked, then fill the second list item with the second item clicked, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to loop over every item in the list with each click. Instead try something like this:

```
$('.compare-btn input').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function(){
        var me = $(this).attr("refid"); 
        $(".compareTray ul li:not(:has(>img))").first().append('<img src="images/submenu/' + me + '.png" alt="compare1" height="28" width="28" />');
    });
}
```

What this does is find `<li>`'s in the list that do not contain an `<img>`. It then appends the image to the first one found.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4Mw6q/) is a JSFiddle that demonstrates a simplified version of this using buttons instead of checkboxes and divs instead of images.